# Make particles stay on Plane

Tags: particles, physics, collision

I have created a particle effect that is influenced by a vortex.  Now I want to create a plane that is the parent of both of these object.  That way this plane controls the orientation of the emitter and the vortex.  However, when the plane is rotated, I want the moving particles to stay oriented so that they are on the plane, as if they are "sticking" to it.
The overall result should be a plane that has particles spinning in a vortex pattern. where u can rotate the plane and the particles will rotate along with it, giving the visual of a particle disk.

How do I make the particles orient with the plane at all times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Collider

Add a cube and parent it to the plane that the particles should remain within.
[image: 1]

Scale the cube so that it is very thin and large enough to encompasses the simulation area.
[image: 2]

In the *Physics Properties* tab, add a *Collision* modifier and set *Damping* to 1 to keep the particles from bouncing inside too much.
[image: 3]

If particles are leaking out, change the integration model or increase the simulation subframes.
[image: 4]

### Result

[image: 5]

Answer (score 6):

### Opposing Wind Forces

Create two equal *Wind* force fields like in the image below.
[image: 1]

Set the *Strength* of both fields to a high value and make sure that there is some falloff.
[image: 2]

As long as these two forces are equal and parented to a plane (or any object), all particles should stay pretty close to the plane between the two force fields.
[image: viola]

Comment: I had some issues with this method.  I tried some simple rotation animation, and it would work fine until it stopped moving.  Then it would go wonky as it balanced itself out.  It would spread and wobble a bit.  I like your idea but I'm not sure if it will work properly, as I do not want the particles to deform or wobble.

Comment: I believe that stronger forces with sharper falloffs could reduce the wobbling, but I have another solution in the works ;)

Comment: cool, hit me with it when u've finished!  I'll keep that other idea in mind as well!